# Is there a valid use case for the using namespace directive?

Tags: c++, use-case, namespace

I looked trough some of my older code and found that I was using the `using namespace` directive. From what I read in a lot of google results, it seems that it is never a good idea to use this. Is there actually a valid use case for this construct or was this just a misguided attempt to make peoples lifes easier, that failed?

Comment: Maybe your google results are just misguided, or you misinterpreted them, hard to tell since you "forgot" to give any reference.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, certainly there are valid uses for the `using namespace`-directive.

For example, if you want to use user-defined literals, there operators must be in-scope, so:

```
using namespace std::literals;
```

Or maybe only

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
```

Generally, `using namespace` is unconscionable when you don't know the exact contents, now and in the future, of the respective namespace. If you do, you are fine. But the poster-child of `using namepace`-abuse, namespace `std`, is far too big, amorphous and changing for considering it.

Comment: So basically anything out of house should not be using 'using namespace'? But also you can't really know the future of your own code, so wouldn't it be better to just not use it at all?

Comment: Personally I find the advice not to use `using namespace` statements to be primarily applicable to header files. For source files I’d use them whenever practical. Admittedly that’s not very frequently.

Answer (score 3):

The `using namespace` directive is useful when you have namespaces that identify your project.

Say you have a project that uses the `developerIdentifier::projectName` namespaces. That project has a class `exampleClass` and a set of utility functions under the namespace `utils`. The fully qualified names of these are `developerIdentifier::projectName::exampleClass` and `developerIdentifier::projectName::utils`.

---

You have the header stub `exampleClass.hpp`:

```
#include "utils.hpp"

namespace developerIdentifier {
namespace projectName {
class exampleClass
{
public:
    void function1();
    void function2();
};
}
}
```

The matching implementation file `exampleClass.cpp`has `using namespace developerIdentifier::projectName;` written at the top:

```
using namespace developerIdentifier::projectName;

void exampleClass::function1() { return utils::frobnicate(1, 2); };
void exampleClass::function2() {};
```

Because this `using namespace` declaration is in the implementation file it won't pollute the namspace of any classes importing `exampleClass.hpp`.

This declaration has two benefits:

1. You don't have to write fully qualified function signatures like `void developerIdentifier::projectName::exampleClass::function1()` within `exampleClass.cpp`.
2. You don't have to fully qualify `developerIdentifier::projectName::utils::frobnicate()` within `function1()`.

Comment: Well, there's nothing stopping you from using the same pattern in the implementation-file as in the header...